# Do the German 'von' and English 'from' share the same root?

Tags: etymology, prepositions

I was wondering whether *von* and *from* shared the same common root.

They do have a quite close meaning, and the pronunciation sounds similiar too.

**EDIT**
I had already looked at the relative Wiktionary entries ([1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from#Etymology),[2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/von#Etymology)), and they didn't seem to be that connected after all; that's why I was curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they have separate roots. See [von](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/von) and [from](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from).

The German [von](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/von) is more related to the English [of](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of#English).

Answer (score 6):

Wiktionary to the rescue!

[**from:**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from#Etymology)

> From Middle English *from* (“from”), from Old English *from*, *fram* (“forward, from”), from Proto-Germanic **fram* (“forward, from, away”), from Proto-Indo-European **pr-*, **pro-*, **perəm-*, **prom-* (“forth, forward”) from **por-* (“forward, through”). Cognate with Old Saxon and Old High German *fram* (“from”), Danish *fra* (“from”), Swedish *fram* (“forth, forward”), Swedish *från* (“from”), Icelandic *fram* (“forward, on”), Icelandic *frá* (“from”). More at [fro](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fro).

[**von:**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/von#Etymology)

> From Middle High German *von* (“from”), from Old High German *fon*, *fona* (“from”), from Proto-Germanic **afána*, **fana-*, **funa-* (“from”), compound of **áfa* ( from Proto-Indo-European **apo*, **ap-* (“from, off”)) + **ana* ( from Proto-Indo-European **ano* (“on”)). Cognate with Old Saxon *fana*, *fan* (“from”), Old Frisian *fon* (“from”), Old English *of* (“from”). More at [of](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of), [on](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on).

Comment: i can't see any clear indication that they are related from what you posted :)

Comment: Precisely. It's pretty clear to me that they are not.

Comment: It would be helpful to have that conclusion in the answer itself.

Comment: it would also be interesting to check how reliable wiktionary is, at least in this case, seeing how it seems to be the source of every answer